# Can i try failed quests again?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have 4 failed quests at the moment.

- Fake Papers
- Bitter harvest
- Defender of the Faith
- The Gang of Novigrad

I was wondering if i will ever be able to try them again so i can still try to complete them (or only some of them). If so how can i manage to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without loading a previous save or starting the game over, no. Those quests are gone for good.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can but you have to use the console command mod and then find the right sq name. addfact(sq_x)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is not very helpful. Where can that mod be found? How do you activate the console after installing the mod? And how does one find "the right sq name"?